# How to Calculate One-way Packet Delay without using NTP, PTP

Tags: networking

I am looking for the way to calculate the one-way delay in a packet-switched network. I do not want to use NTP or PTP (Network Time Protocol, Precision Time Protocol).

Consider the scenario:

Host-1 Sends the packet to Host-2. Both Hosts have different Clock rates and the hosts are located in different countries.

Packet may be UDP/TCP/Layer 2 Frame.

Is there any way to sync the clock rates of two hosts so as to calculate the one-way delay.

Now how do you guys calculate the one way delay without relying on a timing protocol. I am looking some generic formula to do this.

I would much appreciate the answers for this question.

Thanks a ton in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Synchronizing clocks is exactly what [S]NTP are meant to accomplish.  If there was a simpler way, the protocols would be simpler.  You can approximate RTT without them, but one-way delay is hard to do.

Answer (score 5):

No, you cannot. Measuring a one-way delay **requires** synchronized clocks (and NTP is typically not good enough for this task, independent synch to reliable clocks is necessary).

Read [RFC 4656](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4656.txt) for the gory details. There are two available implementations, [OWAMP](http://e2epi.internet2.edu/owamp/) in C and [Jowamp](http://www.av.it.pt/jowamp/) in Java.

Comment: bortzmeyer : Thank you so much. If you any more code/link of bit explanation by you could of great help. i will check your links.

Thanks once again :)

Answer (score 0):

refer to `UTP` in bittorrent, it calcs qdelay, no need to sync at both sides, however, it may be not what you want.

Answer (score -3):

I use [iperf](http://sourceforge.net/projects/iperf) to do network testing like that.  You might get some insight by looking at how they do it.

Comment: iperf does not give you one way delay.

Comment: Indeed, iperf is completely unrelated to one-way delay measurement.